# Graphs in C++ Using Adjacency Matrix and List

Tags: c++, graph, linked-list

I am currently working on a small assignment using Graphs to display characters in an adjacency list.  Normally our professor supplies us with examples from class that he works out, however he has not given us any examples this time. This is just a one point extra credit assignment but the real reason I am seeking help is the fact that we have a 50 point in class assignment Friday.  Me nor my other classmates know what is going on currently.  This is the function that I cannot get.

My main question is how would I convert the string * value returned by the 
split function to use in a call to the markEdge function?

```
void loadListFromFile(Graph& g, string filename) {
     /* TODO (1):
     *
     * Open the file and update the matrix with the proper
     * edge status, i.e. 1 if there is an edge from source
     * to target.
     * 
     * The file format is:
     * 
     * sourceNode adjacentNode1 adjacentNode2 ...adjacentNode3
     * 
     * Each node is a single character in the range A-Z.
     */

    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(filename);

    if (ifs.is_open() ==  false){
        cerr << "Error opening file for reading." << endl;
    }

    string line;
    int tokenCount;

    getline( ifs, line);

    while (!ifs.eof()){

        split(line, ' ', tokenCount);

        getline(ifs, line);
    }

}// end loadListFromFile()
```

Here is a given function used to split the values

```
//given
string * split(const string& str, const char delimiter, int& tokenCount){
string * fields = nullptr;
tokenCount = 0;

string token;
string remaining = str;
if (remaining.back() == '\n') {
    remaining.pop_back();
}
remaining.push_back(delimiter);

size_t delimiterPos = remaining.find_first_of(delimiter, 0);
while ( delimiterPos != string::npos ) {
    token = remaining.substr(0, delimiterPos);
    remaining = remaining.substr(delimiterPos + 1);

    if ( fields ) {
        // resize array and add new token.
        string * fieldsTmp = new string [tokenCount + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= tokenCount - 1; i++) {
            fieldsTmp[i] = fields[i];
        }
        fieldsTmp[tokenCount++] = token;

        delete [] fields;
        fields = fieldsTmp;
        fieldsTmp = nullptr;

    } else {
        // create array and add first token.
        fields = new string[tokenCount + 1];
        fields[tokenCount++] = token;
    }
    delimiterPos = remaining.find_first_of(delimiter, 0);
}
return fields;
}// end split()
```

Here is a function that I believe is right.

```
void markEdge(const int fromIndex, const char node) {
    /* TODO (1):
     * Add the node to the list at index fromIndex.
     */

    adjList->pushAt(fromIndex, node);
```

}// end markEdge()

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `string *`.  Dynamic arrays in C++ is most effectively done by using `std::vector`.

Comment: please clarify if string is a typedef of a c-string or a c++ string.  If it is an actual c++ string, you can use the method string::c_string() to do that conversion.  Based on the fact that you are returning pointers I am assuming that this is actually a typedef of a c-string.  If so, you may be able to pass it directly as const will promote a c-string to a const c-string.  Once again this all depends on what string actually is.

Comment: I'm still not able to come up with the solution.  How would the string * be used as a character.  It looks like there is an array of strings but in order to call the other function I need a character.